# google site tag resuts

Tags: google

If I go to http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/robots.txt I get:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Allow: /
```

That means that crawlers are allowed to fully access the website and index everything. If so then why `site:sppp.rajasthan.gov.` in on Google Search shows me only  few pages whereas it contains lots of documents including PDF files?

Comment: You may want to read [what is on-topic here](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Robots exclusion standard protocol is also a security issue of course :)

Answer (score 1):

By writing:

```
User-agent:*
Disallow:
Allow: /
```

You are saying to the robots: *everything is allowed and nothing is disallowed*. This may be confusing for robots.

I suggest you to write those rules of  [Robots Exclusion Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) clearer by changing the content of your `robots.txt` file to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

**Or:**

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

This way you are allowing robots to index everything.